# Convert system of second order PDEs to a system of first order PDEs

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I am attempting so convert

$$H_t = D_H H_{xx} - vH_x - \alpha H Z$$

$$Z_t = D_Z Z_{xx} + \beta H Z $$

into a system of first order equations. $D_H$, $D_Z$, $\alpha$ and $v$ are constants and $H$ and $Z$ describe the population of humans and zombies which interact as with the equations above.

Following the post from Harry49 in [>>here<<](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2063571/convert-second-order-pde-u-tt-u-xx-u-to-a-system-of-first-order-pdes/2977669#2977669) I first tried to rewrite the equations as a linear system of balance laws $\mathbf{q_t + A ~ q_x = S ~ q}$ where $\mathbf{q}$ = $(H, H_x, H_t, Z, Z_x, Z_t)^T$.

This gives me

$$\begin{bmatrix} H_t \\ H_{xt} \\ H_{tt} \\ Z_t \\ Z_{xt} \\ Z_{tt} \end{bmatrix} + \mathbf{A} \begin{bmatrix} H_x \\ H_{xx} \\ H_{tx} \\ Z_x \\ Z_{xx} \\ Z_{tx} \end{bmatrix}  = \mathbf{S} \begin{bmatrix} H \\ H_{x} \\ H_{t} \\ Z \\ Z_{x} \\ Z_{t} \end{bmatrix}$$

My next step would be to determine the coefficients of the matrices $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{S}$, which is where I get confused due to the coefficients that couple the equations. I am not even sure if the approach I chose is a legitimate one for my kind of problem and would appreciate any kind of help!

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic idea is to introduce new variables $X = H_x$, $Y = Z_x$, that gives directly:
$$
H_t = D_H X_x - v H_x - \alpha H Z \\
X   = H_x \\
Z_t = D_Z Y_x + \beta H Z \\
Y   = Z_x
$$

Comment: @ViennaFormulaTeam Since your system is not hyperbolic, you will not get directly a linear system of balance laws. However, you may be able to do so by introducing a small parameter $\epsilon > 0$ such that $\epsilon X_t + X = H_x$ and $\epsilon Y_t + Y = Z_x$, and then take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.